# Least $j$ such that $j^2 - k$ is a square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a positive integer $k$, how do we find the least integer $j$ such that $j^2-k$ is a perfect square?

E.g. say $k = 75 = 25 \times 3 = 15 \times 5$. How do we know that the least $j$ in this case is $\frac 12 (15+5) = 10$ and not $\frac 12 (25+3) = 14$?

Comment: I'm tempted to say "because $10 < 14$". What kind of answer are you looking for? Of all the pairs $x, y$ that makes $xy = k$, the one pair with the smallest sum $x + y$ is where $x$ and $y$ are closest in value. Is that what you're looking for? In that case, let $x$ be the largest factor of $k$ that is less than or equal to $\sqrt k$, and let $y = k/x$, and you're there.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that:

$$j^2-k=a^2$$

then:

$$k=j^2-a^2=(j-a)(j+a)$$

If you know factorization of $k$, that means all pair of $(m,n)$ such that:

$$mn=k$$

You can find solution of system of equations:

$$n=j+a$$
$$m=j-a$$
For all $m,n$. Adding this equation side by side you have:

$$j=\frac{m+n}{2}$$

So the less $j$ corresponds to pair $m,n$ where mean:

$$\frac{m+n}{2}$$

is the smallest possible.